# How to pass query string parameters to a bgf-pagination directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to use [this angular directive](https://github.com/begriffs/angular-paginate-anything) to paginate my results.

```
<bgf-pagination
  collection="someVariable"
  url="'http://api.server.com?sort_by={{sortBy}}'">
</bgf-pagination>
```

The problem is that the directive requests my url before to compile {{sortBy}} and it breaks my application.

How can I change that?

Comment: I would also suggest changing the subject to something about bgf-pagination-related, like: How to pass query string parameters to a bgf-pagination directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://github.com/begriffs/angular-paginate-anything) states:

> url-params:
>
> > map of strings or objects which will be turned to ?key1=value1&key2=value2 after the url

So, I'm guessing (I've never used this directive) that you could do:

```
<bgf-pagination
  collection="someVariable"
  url="'http://api.server.com'"
  url-params="{sort_by: sortBy}">
</bgf-pagination>
```

Comment: It works, I tried with url-params="{sort_by: {{sortBy}}}"> that's why it didn't work. Thanks